# How to draw 2D Segment Delaunay Graphs in CGAL?

Tags: c++, visualization, graph-theory, cgal, delaunay

I am trying to reproduce the visualizations shown on the [user manual for 2D Segment Delaunay Graphs](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2/index.html):
[image: The segment Voronoi diagram for a set of weakly (left) and strongly (right) intersecting sites.]

However, I am struggling to understand how approach this issue. Concretely, how would I draw the graph corresponding to the `SDG2` object created and populated in the following snippet?

```
// standard includes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

// define the kernel
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;

// typedefs for the traits and the algorithm
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_traits_2<Kernel>  Gt;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_2<Gt>             SDG2;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream ifs("data/sites2.cin");
  assert( ifs );

  SDG2          sdg;
  SDG2::Site_2  site;

  // read the sites from the stream and insert them in the diagram
  while ( ifs >> site ) { sdg.insert( site ); }

  ifs.close();

  // validate the diagram
  assert( sdg.is_valid(true, 1) );
  cout << endl << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have already seen that the `Segment_Delaunay_Graph_2` class exposes the function [`draw_dual`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2/classCGAL_1_1Segment__Delaunay__graph__2.html#a22eca07c01535722975450d1db60ce66) that takes a stream and outputs the sites. When passing `std::cout`, the sites were simply printed to the standard output, which is nice, but far from a visualization.

Looking at other examples (e.g. `CGAL-5.0/demo/interpolation/surface_voronoi.cpp`), I see that one can use a `CGAL::Geomview_stream` and pass this to the `draw_dual` function, but I am unsure if the same applies to the `draw_dual` function defined in `Segment_Delaunay_Graph_2`.

Comment: BTW, visualization with Geomview is not supported by CGAL anymore - the last version which had it was 5.3.2

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know. In fact, I am working with the `CGAL-5.0` examples. What would be a better alternative for versions above 5.3.2 then?

Comment: There is an overloaded function `CGAL::draw`, which can draw **some** CGAL objects - however the `Segment_Delaunay_Graph_2` is not among them (for now). This function uses the Qt5 for actual drawing. Another way is to use **ipelets** - it looks like something similar (by design) to the Geomview, but more modern.